# database design for composite elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm building a site that tracks donations and sales of items in a school auction.

Items can be sold individually or in lots, which are just groups of items bundled for sale as a single unit (like a gift certificate for a dinner Item bundled with a gift certificate for movie tickets Item).

Both of these things (Items and Lots) share fields like name, description, value. But Items have additional fields, like the donor, restrictions of use, type of item, etc.

I started by creating a table called Lot and an association table that lets Lots contain 1+ Items.

That works great for Lots. But that leaves me with a problem:

When Buyers win I need to record the win and the price. I'm doing that with a Win table that associates the Buyer with the Lot and the winning price.

But how do I deal with all the Items that aren't assigned to Lots? Should every item be in a Lot, just singly? That would make sense because it would work with the Win table scheme above, but I would need to automatically create a Lot for every Item that isn't already in another Lot. Which seems weird.

I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I can't figure it out!

Thanks!

Comment: use table inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of treating every item as a lot should be the winning one. It may sound weird, but it will make things way easier in the long run.

I have to deal on a daily base with a database where a similar problem was 'solved' the other way round, meaning keeping bundles of items and items apart and that proved to be a great pita (and for sure I'm not talking about a flat round bread here).

This database is both backbone for statistical evaluations and a bunch of (web) applications and on countless occasions I run into trouble when deciding which table to chose or how to level the differences between those two groups in querying and in coding.

So, even if your project will be rather small eventually, that is a good idea.

Yes, you need to provide a method to put every item in a lot, but this trouble is to be taken just once. On the other hand your queries wouldn't become significantly more complex because of that 'extra' table, so I'd definitely would chose this way.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. So... to take this route, every time a new item is created, I would automatically create a new lot with that item. And if I delete an item, I'd need to check before_destroy that any Lots that *only* contained that item were also deleted. Additionally, a lot with only a single item would probably default to using that item's name and description as the lot's name and description. There would be lots of little diligence bits like that. With @jvillian 's polymorphic approach I'd need to type check a lot (was the win a lot or an item?) which seems less clean, no?

Comment: When writing this I actually didn't think so much about clean or not clean, but more of the implications. By now you've got three other opinions and I wouldn't dare to call any of those unclean. Out of bad experience I would choose the option where your data are stored uniformly, because that seems to be a good solid base for coding and querying. If you fear or analyze that necessary activities to achieve that state are too complex, it's perfectly alright to keep items and lots apart. Cheers.

Comment: Well said, @MyBrainHurts!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an Auction model that could have one or many Items. Then you could have two different types of Auctions, Auction::Single and Auction::Lot. Price would be a column on Auction. Auction has many Bids which is a join model between the Auction and the User (or Bidder). That join model would also store the bid price. When the Auction is over, you could create a separate Win record if you want, or just find the Winner through the highest Bid from Auction.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you showed some code. But, what you want is a polymorphic association. So, something like:

```
class Item
  has_one :win, as: :winnable
  belongs_to :lot
end

class Lot
  has_one :win, as: :winnable
  has_many :items
end

class Win
  belongs_to :buyer
  belongs_to :winnable, polymorphic: true
end
```